# how to find average of object with same type of values

Tags: javascript, object, sum

```
let numbers = {
    name:"Faisal", value:20,
    name:"qasim", value:32,
    name:"asim", value:20,
    name:"abid", value:30,
    name:"yaqoob", value:50
};
```

Comment: please add a valid data structure and your try.

Comment: Did you mean `let numbers = [{ name:"Faisal" , value:20}, {name:"qasim" , value:32},{name:"asim" , value:20}, {name:"abid" , value:30}, {name:"yaqoob" , value:50 }]`?

Comment: Your data structure is still invalid. You have multiple properties with the same name.

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you meant to post the following example:

```
let numbers = [
                { name:"Faisal" , value:20}, 
                { name:"qasim" , value:32},
                { name:"asim" , value:20}, 
                { name:"abid" , value:30}, 
                { name:"yaqoob" , value:50 }
              ]
```

Then this should get you the average:

```
var total = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    total += numbers[i].value;
}
var avg = total / numbers.length;
```

alternatively, you do it more concisely with `reduce`, like this:

```
var avg = numbers.reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue) { return accumulator + currentValue.value }, 0) / numbers.length;
```

Comment: You should consider using functional methods. `const avg = numbers.map(n => n.value).reduce((c, n) => (c + n) / 2);`. Functional is fun!